# Thin Groups and Lie Primitive Groups

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $ G(\mathbb{R}) $ be a noncompact Lie group which is the real points of an algebraic group. Let $ \Gamma $ be a closed subgroup of $ G $.

$ \Gamma $ is called Lie primitive if it is not contained in any proper closed positive dimensional subgroup of $ G $.

Is it true that a subgroup $ \Gamma $ is Lie primitive if and only if it is a discrete Zariski dense subgroup of $ G(\mathbb{R}) $?

I'm asking this in response the comment here

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436711/finitely-many-lie-primitive-subgroups?noredirect=1#comment1133074_436711

about thin groups.

Comment: What does the word "proper" mean here? Does it mean strictly containing the given subgroup and strictly less than the ambient Lie group? Or only the latter?

Comment: @MoisheKohan just means strictly less than the ambient Lie group